# Multiple image pull errors before success

Tags: azure-container-instances

I'm using the Azure cli to create ACI instances. The creation is working but is really slow. The Azure Portal seems to have pushed some new changes that now surface the docker logs and I am noticing a distinct pattern where every ACI I create is cycling through 2 image pull failures before it finally succeeds. Here is the error I am seeing:

> Failed to pull image
>   "{myregistry}.azurecr.io/fossil/worker/local:no-branch.ltsc.8": error
>   pulling image configuration: Get dial tcp 52.239.152.234:443:
>   connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I am using a private registry (ACR) and it does eventually succeed, but these failures (and their associated backoffs) are dramatically slowing down my ACI creations.

Any ideas what might cause this and how I can avoid it? ACI creation time is a big deal for our scenario and we are already hindered with the super big Windows images so I want to eliminate any other slowdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating multiple instances at the same time? I'm wondering if you hit the underlying ACR storage I/O OPS limit when pulling images. Windows images are large, ACI caches the latest 3 versions of base image, so try build your image on top of latest images and that may help.

Comment: No in my case I am creating a single ACI and see this. I've seen other reports of the same issue with Windows images. It wouldn't surprise me if it had something to do with the large image size, but still seems like there must be some solution on the ACI end to address this.